# Why is my output from scrabing empty brackets?

Tags: python, ssl

I am trying to scrabe distance in km and time from google maps. 
However, when I run my code. the result is 2 emty brackets. like these:
[]
[]

What am I doing wrong? You can see my code below.
bwt, I am using the 3.5.1 version of python.
I hope you can help me. Thanks Anna.

```
import urllib.request

import re

import ssl


url2 = "https://www.google.dk/maps/dir/Aarhus+Kommune/Horsens+Municipality/@56.0321212,9.6926376,10z/am=t/data=!4m17!4m16!1m5!1m1!1s0x464c4cb9541ed4a9:0xe58661230cfb55d!2m2!1d10.1373728!2d56.1683931!1m5!1m1!1s0x464c721bbef053d9:0xd089bdc7f76375ab!2m2!1d9.7844165!2d55.9267709!2m3!6e1!7e2!8j1465804800"

context1 = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)

htmlfile = urllib.request.urlopen(url2, context=context1)

htmltext = htmlfile.read()

regex = b'<span jstcache="1146">(.+?) km</span>'

regex2 = b'<span jstcache="1145" class="delay-light" jsan="7.delay-light">(.+?)</span>'

pattern = re.compile(regex)

pattern2 = re.compile(regex2)

distance_km = re.findall(pattern,htmltext)

distance_time = re.findall(pattern2,htmltext)

print(distance_km)
print(distance_time)
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why my regexs suddenly lokkes different. They are:

regex = b'<span jstcache="1146">(.+?) km</span>'

regex2 = b'<span jstcache="1145" class="delay-light" jsan="7.delay-light">(.+?)</span>'

Comment: [Don't parse HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2482744). Share the actual version of Python as show by `python --version`, don't just say 'latest'. If something is wrong with the question then edit it, don't comment.

Comment: Make your life easier: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro

Comment: The string `<span jstcache` doesn't appear in the page you get when you load the url in your post. I'd definitely use the API instead - scraping Google's services is against their Terms and Conditions, and the API is very useful

Comment: @AnnaHviidHeickendorff while there are other choices for parsing html, the simple way to make your code work is to fix the regex pattern string, please check the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

In Python Regexp, the `"<>."` characters are of special use, also called `regexp meta chacter`. So when using those character as the original character, make it escaped with a `\` ahead first.

So, the following expression `regex` and `regex2`:

```
regex = b'<span jstcache="1146">(.+?) km</span>'

regex2 = b'<span jstcache="1145" class="delay-light" jsan="7.delay-light">(.+?)</span>'
```

should be:

```
regex = b'\<span jstcache="1146">(.+?) km\</span\>'

regex2 = b'\<span jstcache="1145" class="delay-light" jsan="7\.delay-light">(.+?)\</span\>'
```

Comment: Hi Lulyon

Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, I still gets emty brackets with your code.

Comment: @AnnaHviidHeickendorff I have no clue about what your htmltext is. It is possible to try with half part and more to debug the regex.